# How does $\tan50^\circ$ compare to $1$?

Tags: trigonometry

What is $\tan50^\circ$? (without using a calculator)

1. 1
2. a little less than 1
3. a little bigger than 1
4. none of the above answers

I think the answer is 3, but I can not explain this mathematically. The only logic I came up with is that $45^\circ<50^\circ<60^\circ$ and therefore $\tan45^\circ<\tan50^\circ<\tan60^\circ$; that is $1<\tan50^\circ<\sqrt{3}$.

Is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: Putting (4) in there is pretty mean... how could it be "none of the above" when the exact meaning of (2) and (3) is subjective?

Comment: Why do you conclude 2. while writing $1<\tan50°$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: It was just a typo. I fixed it. Thanks for noticing it.

Comment: @JackM: That was last year exam question in my university; not sure why there is such a choice in the answers, maybe just to make up some possible answers.

Comment: They probably were thinking something along the lines of "50 is a little more than 45, and $\tan$ is increasing, so $\tan(50)$ is a little more than $\tan(45) = 1$". Making d) the correct answer because the difference is not small enough would indeed be rather mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Is there a better approach to this problem?*

No. The only thing needed is mentioning that $\tan x$ is strictly increasing on $\bigg[-
\dfrac\pi2,\dfrac\pi2\bigg]$, which can easily be proven either by drawing the [trigonometric circle](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c7/Tangent-unit-circle.svg/500px-Tangent-unit-circle.svg.png), or by using calculus, since $\tan'x$ $=1+\tan^2x>0$.

Answer (score 5):

Your intuition is correct. If you want to be more precise, observe that 
$$\tan(50) = \tan(45 + 5) = {\tan(45) + \tan(5) \over 1 - \tan(45)\tan(5)}$$
$$= {1 + \tan(5) \over 1 - \tan(5)}$$
Since $\tan(x)$ is very close to ${\pi \over 180} x$ for small $x$, this should be very close to 
$${1 + {\pi \over 36} \over 1 - {\pi \over 36}}$$
This is equal to $1.1912..$, while the true value is $1.1917..$.

Answer (score 1):

The $\tan$ function is growing on $\left[0,\frac{\pi}2\right[$

[image]

We also know that $\tan(\frac{\pi}4)=1$ and $50°>\frac{\pi}4=45°$

What is more around $\frac{\pi}4$ the function has a slope of about 1, therefore a $5°$ difference won't induce a big difference between $\tan(45°)$ and $\tan(50°)$.

Therefore $\tan(50°)$ is a little bigger than $1$ which is answer $3$.

Comment: I think you do need the OP's remark that it's also smaller than $\sqrt 3$, to justify that it's only "a little" bigger than $1$, otherwise it could be anywhere in $[1, \infty)$.

Comment: @JackM Or, could I just say that a $5°$ difference is obviously not a huge difference as $\tan$ does not grow incredibly fast near $\pi/4$ (slope around $1$)?

Comment: I don't really think that's obvious. Besides, the $\sqrt 3$ bound is very simple.

Comment: Yep, the OP's approach was better!

Comment: @YvesDaoust Should I delete mine ?

Comment: @ Hippalectryon: no but you could supplement the solution with a word about the slope. Beware that you know the slope at $45°$, but not at $50°$...

Answer (score 1):

Using the series approximation of cotangent, $\cot{x}\approx\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{3}$,

$$\begin{align}
\tan{\frac{5\pi}{18}}&=\cot{\frac{2\pi}{9}}\\
&\approx \left(\frac{2\pi}{9}\right)^{-1}-\frac13\left(\frac{2\pi}{9}\right)\\
&\approx 1.19968392...
\end{align}$$

Note that this simple two term approximation differs from the true value by less than $0.7\%$.

Comment: Wow, and you can get this result without calculator?

Comment: @Ale As long as you know enough digits of $\pi$, absolutely.

Comment: i should learn them :)

Comment: @Ale Do you at least know $\pi\approx 3.14$? Because that's actually enough here.

Comment: You are absolutely right, my mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

Let me work with radians and let us have a look to $\tan(\frac{5\pi}{18})$. We can write $$\tan(\frac{5\pi}{18})=\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{36})$$ At this point, we could apply the formula for $\tan(a+b)$ and conclude. Another way is to develop $\tan(x)$ as a Taylor series at $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and get $$\tan(x)=1+2 \left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)+O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^2\right)$$ If we use  $x=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{36}$, we then have $$\tan(\frac{5\pi}{18}) \simeq 1+\frac{\pi}{18} \simeq 1.17453$$ while the exact value is $1.19175$.

Another solution is to draw the circle, the line corresponding to the two angles and observe where are located the values of the respective tangents.

Comment: 1.19175 is not the exact value.

Comment: This is probably the approximation I'd go with if I truly was bereft of a calculator, since it requires only two arithmetical steps to compute. +1

Comment: @Anixx 1.19175 is an exact value, to good approximation.

Comment: @David H haha, very funny

Comment: @Anixx. I agree with you but in such a case I give you another wrong answer $1.19175359259420995870530807186041933693070040770854385365483000$

Answer (score 1):

I would draw a $45^\circ-45^\circ-90^\circ$ triangle (tangent $45^\circ$ IS actually 1, of course) and observe the effect on the tangent ratio of increasing one of the $45^\circ$ angles while preserving the $90^\circ$ angle.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\tan(45^o) < \tan(50^o) < \tan(\frac{45^o+60^o}{2})$$

Now, using the formula (which can be deduced easily by writing $\tan=\frac{\sin}{\cos}$) 
$$\tan(\frac{A+B}{2})=\frac{\sin(A)+\sin(B)}{\cos(A)+\cos(B)}$$
we get
$$\tan(\frac{45^o+60^o}{2})=\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}+1}=(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})(\sqrt{2}-1) \sim 1.3$$

Answer (score 0):

The addition formula for $\tan$ is

$$\tan(A+B) = \frac{\tan A + \tan B}{1-\tan A \tan B}$$

Let $A=45^{\circ}$ and $B = 5^{\circ}$. This gives us
$$\tan 50^{\circ} = \frac{\tan 45 + \tan 5}{1-\tan 45 \tan 5}$$
We know that $\tan 45 = 1$ and so

$$\tan 50 = \frac{1+\tan 5}{1-\tan 5}$$

Imagine a right-angled triangle with a $5^{\circ}$ angle. The adjacent side would be much, much longer than the opposite side: $0 < \tan 5 < 1$. It is clear that $\tan 50$ is very close to $1$. But is it bigger than or smaller than $1$? Well, since $0 < \tan 5 < 1$ we have $1+\tan > 1-\tan 5$ and so
$$\frac{1+\tan 5}{1-\tan 5} > 1$$

The answer is (c).