# Exact value of $\tan 50^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

Directly related to: [What is $\tan50^\circ$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/832677/what-is-tan50-circ)

---

$50^\circ = \frac{5\pi}{18} $ is a rational multiple of $\pi$.  Therefore should be related to the ninth roots of unity $e^{\pi i /18}$, but how does one compute the exact value ?

**EDIT** I will settle for the extension $\mathbb{Q}[\tan 50^\circ]$ and the [minimal polynomial](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/galoiscorr.pdf) over $\mathbb{Q}$...

---

Here it is done for the 5-th roots of unity: [How to find the exact value of $ \cos(36^\circ) $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300081/how-to-find-the-exact-value-of-cos36-circ)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One cannot express $\tan(50^\circ)$ purely in terms of *real* radicals. For if one could, then one could express $\cos(20^\circ)$ in terms of real radicals, and it is known that one cannot do that. (It is an instance of the *casus irreducibilis* of the cubic.)

As is implicitly pointed out in the post, one can express $\tan(50^\circ)$ in terms of a primitive ninth root of unity.

**Added:** The edited question asks for the minimal polynomial of $\tan(50^\circ)$. Let $x=\tan(50^\circ)$. Using the identity $\tan(3\theta)=\frac{3\tan\theta -\tan^3\theta}{1-3\tan^2\theta}$, we find that $\frac{3x-x^3}{1-3x^2}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. Square and simplify. We get a sextic in $x$, which is irreducible by the Eisenstein Irreducibility Criterion.

Comment: I was guessing maybe you take two cube roots in different places.

Comment: No combination of real (cube) roots will do it.

Comment: You can still write down roots in cases of [Causis irreducibilis](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466269/working-with-casus-irreducibilis), e.g. $x^3 - 15 x + 4 = (x-4)(x - (2+i))(x-(2-i))$.

Comment: Sure. But not for a cubic irreducible over the rationals, in particular the minimal polynomial of $\cos(20^\circ)$.

Answer (score 0):

We can find **exact value of tan 50∘** (and other integer angles and polygons) using **Precise-Rewritten method**. The result will be in repeated nested radicals.

For this our target angle is 50∘. Make a table having three columns starting from 90∘ (called as **Central**):

First column is the Central and its halves. Each Central requires to add or subtract towards target angle (A, which is 50∘ in this case).

Second column is the cumulative of the first column excluding 90∘. We need to reach to the target angle A in this column.

Third column is just $\frac{previous Central}{current Central}$, which is, always, either +2 or -2.
Let us see the calculation as:[image]

In the table, we can see there is repetition of +2-2+2. We are lucky, we are near to the exact radical values for Sin 50∘.

Now, gather the result from the third column as: $$+2 \overline {+2 - 2 + 2}$$.

Replace each by √(2 as: $$√(2 \overline {+√(2 -√(2 +√(2}$$.

Half of this is Sin 50∘ as $$\frac{1}{2}√(2 \overline {+√(2 -√(2 + √(2} ]$$ 
Subtract the whole thing after first radical, it will be Cos 50∘ as $$\frac{1}{2}√(2 - \overline {+√(2 -√(2 + √(2}]$$

Now,we can use classical formula for $\tan 50∘$, although **Precise-Rewritten method** prescribed something else.
$$\tan 50∘ = \frac{\frac{1}{2}√(2 \overline {+√(2 -√(2 + √(2} ]}{\frac{1}{2}√(2 - \overline {+√(2 -√(2 + √(2}]}$$

Therefore, $$\tan 50∘ = \frac{√(2 \overline {+√(2 -√(2 + √(2} ]}{√(2 - \overline {+√(2 -√(2 + √(2}]}$$

Note: Closing brackets collapsed for easy only.

Source: Breaking Classical Rules in Trigonometry: Precise-Rewritten method